# What's the definition of Ellipse?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, conic-sections

I needed to prove that a parametric curve is an Ellipses and only then I realized that the Ellipses were not defined in the textbook.

However, I could not use the definition for the "standard" Ellipses where
$$\frac{x(t)^2}{a^2}+\frac{y(t)^2}{a^2}=1  $$ because it's a generalized ellipses with rotation. I could not really use the General ellipse
$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 +Dx+Ey+F=0, B^2-4AC<0$$ because then there was no point of the proof.

The only sensible definition I found from the Wikipedia was

> Any ellipse is an affine image of the unit circle with equation $x^2+y^2=1$

But that had gone a bit outside the scope of the course.

What's the definition of Ellipse? How am I suppose to say mathematically that an Ellipses is an Ellipses?

Comment: What was the curve you needed to show was an ellipse?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ each multiplied by some constant orthogonal vector, i.e. an affine image of the unit circle by definition. I needed to show that it's an Ellipses

Comment: I wonder if you're meant to use singular value decomposition

Comment: Could you write out the formulas given in the problem?

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is an ellips, $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is a hyperbola. Question: do you, by translating and rotating your $X$- and $Y$-axis, end up with the ellips or with the hyperbola formula? (... or are you dealing with the special case, the parabola?)

Comment: What you show in your query as first equation results a circle, not an ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Any ellipse has the form of a deformed circle along any axis $$(x'(s),y'(s))= s (x \cos \phi + y \sin\phi, -x \cos \phi+y \cos \phi)$$

$$ x^2+y^2=1  \longrightarrow  \left( \cos \phi\  (a x) + \sin \phi\  (b y)\right)^2 + 
  \left(-\sin \phi\  (a x) + \cos \phi \  (b y) \right) ^2, $$
its center translated by any vector $(x_0,y_0)$
$$\longrightarrow \left( \cos \phi\  (a\ (x-x_0) + \sin \phi\  (b \ (y-y_0)\right)^2 + 
  \left(-\sin \phi\  (a \ (x-x_0)) + \cos \phi \  (b \ (y-y_0)) \right) ^2  $$

Now, using Mathematica for short,

```
   1=(Cos[\[Phi]] (a (x - x0)) + 
    Sin[\[Phi]] (b (y - y0)))^2 + (-Sin[\[Phi]] (a (x - x0)) + 
      Cos[\[Phi]] (b (y - y0)))^2 // Expand // FullSimplify
```

$$1=a^2 (x-\text{x0})^2+b^2 (y-\text{y0})^2$$

On paper, complete the squares of x,y and collect all additive constants

$$A x^2 + B x = A \ \left(x^2 + \frac{B x}{A}  + 
 \frac{B^2}{4 A^2}\right) - \frac{B^2}{4 A}
 = A \left(x +\frac{B}{2 A} \right)^2 - \frac{B^2}{4 A}$$

The coefficients of the complete squares have to be positive, the constant negative. Different signs yield a hyperbola, one sign zero with a linear term a parabola.

The constant zero a pair of lines, two positive coefficients and a zero constant a point.

Easier classification of quadratic forms via projective geometry.

Comment: What's "collect all additive constants" and "one sign zero with a linear"? where did $y$ go?

Comment: The summed constants arising as compensates of the complete squares. If there is no bilinear term, the same procdure for the y-part is done. The total algorithm with a mixed term  $ x y$ amounts to find the angle $\phi$ of  the axis  and reconstructing the rotated, axis aligned form. By considering the fundamental form of the double line or point,  $(0,1) = (x-y)^2 = x^2 -2   x y + y^2$ ,  its clear, that the total analysis  for all values of a in $a x y $ yields to many different cases in order to be presented in other fromes than by a table or logical case algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a few different ways to define an ellipse but one definition is: the set of all points where the sum of the distances between a given point and two fixed points (the foci) is constant (the constant is the length of the major axis).  Watch the bottom bar at the bottom of this animation - the two lengths change but the sum doesn't.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLjnTgXXgXk

Answer (score 1):

You are given the parametric equation
$$
P=\vec a\cos t+ \vec b\sin t
$$
If $\vec a\perp\vec b$ then you can choose orthogonal cartesian axes directed as $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ so that:
$$
x(t)=|\vec a|\cos t,\quad y(t)=|\vec b|\sin t
$$
and from these you get
$$
{x^2\over |\vec a|^2}+{y^2\over |\vec b|^2}=1.
$$
It can be proved that this equation also holds for an ellipse
in oblique coordinates, hence the above proof works even if $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are not orthogonal.
In that case $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ give direction and magnitude of a pair of conjugate semidiameters of the ellipse.

Comment: That's part of what I did. But how does it work for "oblique coordinates"? If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ were not orthogonal, the denominator is not exactly $|\vec a|^2$ and $|\vec b|^2$ is it?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Denominators are exactly $|\vec a|^2$ and $|\vec b|^2$, but coordinates $x$ and $y$ are to be computed parallel to the axes, see here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Oblique_Coordinate_System